# Compile error: type mismatch in sum loop, excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, compiler-errors, type-mismatch

```
   Dim SumEIP(1 To 708, 1 To 200) As Long
   Dim EIP(1 To 708, 1 To 200) As Integer
   Dim IP(1 To 708, 1 To 200) As Variant
   Dim LeadTime(1 To 708) As Integer
   Dim SR(1 To 708, 1 To 200) As Integer
   Dim CumReceipt(1 To 708, 1 To 200) As Integer  


Sub test()

  For i = 1 To 708

  LeadTime(i) = 5

  Next i

                For i = 1 To 708
                    For t = 1 To 60
                        For p = 1 To 2
                                Sum = SumEIP + EIP(p, t)
                        Next p
                                SumEIP(i, t) = Sum
                                Sum = 0
                                EIP(i, t) = IP(i, t) + SumEIP(i, t)

                         ''For C = 1 To LeadTime(i) - 1
                         ''   SumReceipts = SumReceipts + SR(i, t + C)
                         ''Next C
                         ''       CumReceipt(i, t) = SumReceipts
                         ''       SumReceipts = 0

                    Next t
                Next i
 End Sub
```

Whenever I run the uncommented piece of code I get a compile error: type mismatch  and Excel highlights the + sign before EIP(p,t).

However, when I run the commented part of code, I do not get this error. I cannot find the difference between the two explaining the difference in errors. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to declare the variables correctly, if you are getting a Type mismatch

Comment: Change this line of code from:  Sum = SumEIP + EIP(p, t)  to:  Sum = Sum + EIP(p, t).

Comment: Hi, could you add a little more detail, I'm not sure I'm following

Comment: When you get the type mismatch, what content do the variables have? IP is declared as variant so can contain anything whereas EIP is Integer and SUMEIP is Long. If those are all supposed to be whole numbers, declare all as Long.

Comment: Where are `I`, `p` and `t` declared?

Comment: Brian M Stafford, that solved my problem, thank you very much for your quick response! Same goes for the other repliers, Thanks!